# Add new contact with RingCentral API

Tags: java, contacts, addressbook, ringcentral

I want to develop application in Java where it can add new contact in address book with all its related details. I need a backend RC API to do that task for me and will be called from my application.

What is the most relevant RC API to do that?

So far, I searched all the APIs present in the API references here:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference

Which endpoint can a contact in the existing address book of RC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an endpoint "Creates personal user contact " for creating new contact:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/External-Contacts/createContact

Sample:

`POST /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/address-book/contact`

```js
{
  "firstName":"David",
  "lastName":"Williams",
  "businessPhone":"+15551234567",
  "businessAddress":{
    "street":"20 Davis Dr.",
    "city":"Belmont",
    "state":"CA",
    "zip":94002
  }
}
```

ref: https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/1054/add-a-contact-name-number-to-contacts-via-api.html